# Choosing a section title for scientific papers: "How it works" or "How does it work?"

Tags: grammar

I am writing a scientific paper and confused with choosing the correct form to use as the section title.

Which one is the correct one?

> How it works

or

> How does it work?

Comment: Related: [What's the semantic difference between “How did I <verb> <subject>” and “How I <verb in past tense> <subject>”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6696/)

Answer (score 7):

As [J. M. wrote](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6875/choosing-a-section-title-for-scientific-papers-how-it-works-or-how-does-it-wo/6876#6876), both are correct.  However, using a complete sentence as a section heading (“How does it work?”) sounds more friendly/casual/informal than using a noun phrase (“How it works”) to me, and it may be good or bad depending on the style of your paper.

I also agree to J. M. that using “it” in a heading may not be the best choice.

Comment: "how does it work" sounds informal? Really?

Comment: Huh? Why the downvote? :o Anyway, I upvoted this.

Comment: "How it works" is certainly more formal, at least in my opinion. I would avoid using a question as a heading in formal writing. But then, this is a matter of preference.

Comment: I don't know why I downvote this answer. OK. I upvote now :-)

Comment: @Jimi: as always, a matter of ear. ;) FWIW, I've seen both forms in the scientific literature.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the flow and the titles of the immediately previous sections.  For example:

**Introduction**

The new cure for the disease[...]

**How it was Discovered**

It all started with some mold on a petri dish[...]

**How it Works**

Magic.

***Versus:***

**Introduction**

[...]

**Why is this important?**

[...]

**How does it work?**

[...]

Answer (score 2):

Either of the two is okay; I would however recommend replacing "it" with the actual object under consideration if that is to be a section's title.